# User badge details page: redundant or misplaced earned icon and tooltip?

Tags: feature-request, badges, user-interface

I was looking at a couple of my badges to see which questions I earned them on, and noticed a funny little green checkmark next to the badge tag that seemed a bit out of place. The tooltip for it is nearly identical to the text that is shown underneath my avatar:

[image]

I find the icon and tooltip slightly redundant, or at the very least, rendered in the wrong place. I'm suggesting a more useful location for the green checkmark in my drawing above.

Now, compare this to the page you see when you have NOT earned a badge:

[image]

There's no icon next to the tag badge here, but to follow suit on the earned page, perhaps a nice red cross next to the text "did not earn this badge" would be nice.

Comment: I suspect this is for consistency with the "full page" view - delete `?userid=<yourID>` from the end of the URL and it lists recent earners, rather than just you; unless you're the most recent, putting it next to your name isn't much help!